# Tracing a task-based application with OMPT

Tags: task, openmp, trace

I am trying to use OMPT to trace a task-based application.

These are the compile options I used to compile the LLVM OpenMP runtime:

```
cmake ../openmp -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DOPENMP_ENABLE_LIBOMPTARGET=OFF -DLIBOMP_OMPT_OPTIONAL=ON
```

I am using Clang 13 and the latest LLVM OpenMP runtime from the official github repo.

My application is composed of several nested tasks using `#pragma omp task depend (inout:some_vector[0:some_limit])`

I registered several OMPT callbacks including `ompt_callback_task_create`, `ompt_callback_dependences`, `ompt_callback_task_schedule` that are running properly and giving me the wanted feedback.

However, some callbacks are not being run: `ompt_callback_task_dependence`(while there is dependencies between tasks...) and `ompt_callback_work` even if their registering with `ompt_set_callback` returns code 5 which corresponds to `ompt_set_always`.

What should I do to get those callback to work? Am I missing on something here? I also tried using different runtimes/compilers without any result.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the specifications, I believe it is possible that an `ompt_callback_task_dependence` event is not raised in the case where the predecessor completed before the successor' creation.
Take a look at the minimal example bellow with >1 thread.

The producer thread creates 'A' and sleeps for 1 s.
In parallel, another thread consumes 'A', completes it and can destroy it.
Then, 1 s. later, the producer thread wake up and creates 'B'.
Since 'A' completed, there is no need to "make 'B' depends on it" (it may even no longer exists on the runtime-side, so the dependency cannot tracked).

```
# pragma omp task depend(out: x) // A
{}

sleep(1);

# pragma omp task depend(in: x) // B
{}
```

Comment: To avoid 'missing' dependences using `ompt_callback_task_dependence`, one should use the `ompt_callback_dependences` events and re-process dependencies (in, out, inoutset...) on their own